# If user scrolling to fast enter in a infinite scrolling in FlatLIst in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

Currently I am facing a logic problem. I want to make a FlatList in which the user need to keep scrolling down in the want to see more news, as Facebook does it. So basically so far I am facing a bug if the user scroll to fast you get in a infinite loop because it keep moves it and keep fetching.

This is my code:

```
    <FlatList
      ref= {(list) => this.feed = list}
      data={data}
      onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
        />
      }
    />

  async onEndReached() {
    if (this.state.loading) return;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    await fetchFeed(from);
    this.setState({ loading: false });

    this.feed.scrollToIndex({ viewPosition: 0.4 });
  }
```

My problem is that the scroll is still going down even when the user stop pressing. I was trying to use onMomentum property but the problem still there.

Comment: Updated my answer. This logic could end your infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `react-native`, but I would set a timeout and have a `Boolean` to block any new scrolling-area for maybe `500 ms`. I use this logic when things goes "to fast" sometimes.

This is one of a few ways you can do it in JavaScript:

```js
var button      = document.getElementById("button");
var timeout     = undefined,
    timeout2,
    continue_0  = false;

function go () {

    if (continue_0) {
        // Your code when everything is OK here
        button.innerHTML = "ON";
        
        clearTimeout(timeout2);
        timeout2 = setTimeout(() => { // just an example timeout
            
            button.innerHTML = "OFF";
        }, 500);
        
        continue_0 = false;
    } else {

        if (timeout === undefined) {

            button.innerHTML = "OFF";
            clearTimeout(timeout2);
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                
                timeout     = undefined;
                continue_0  = true;
                button.innerHTML = "You can turn ON now";

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
button.addEventListener("click", go);
```

```html
<h3>Wait 1 sec. to turn "On" - After Click</h3>
<button id="button" style="padding: 30px;">OFF</button>
```

You could also just remove an event-listener and the reattach it after X-seconds; i.e. like this `document.body.removeEventListener("click", go);`.